# Capybara having trouble finding and filling in first form element

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, capybara, rspec-rails

It appears that Capybara is unable to find the first form element on a page by the *displayed text* within that form-element's label.

Capybara can however find that first form-element by that label's `for` value, which seems odd.  I'm thinking the DOM just hasn't loaded yet, and Capybara can continuously search for `for` values but not the displayed text within `labels`?

Here is what my relevant form elements look like:

[image: relevant form elements]

so I should be able to grab each of these elements by the displayed Label text by saying:

```
fill_in "First Name", with: "foo"
fill_in "Last Name", with: "bar"
fill_in "Title", with: "some title"
```

Here is my spec:

```
scenario "with minimum fields while passing validations", js: true do
  visit "/"
  click_link "New Contact"
  fill_in "First Name", with: "foo"
  fill_in "Last Name", with: "bar"
  fill_in "Title", with: "some title"

  click_button "Create Contact"
  expect(page).to have_content "Success."
  expect(page).to have_content "foo bar"
end
```

It is not finding the `First Name` form element so it isn't filling it in.  It finds the Last Name element and the Title element just fine because I am assuming that the DOM has fully loaded by that time:

[image: not filling in first name]

This is the html:

[image: the html]

However, oddly enough: when I change filling in the First name from:

```
fill_in "First Name, with: "foo"
```

To:

```
fill_in "contact_first_name, with: "foo"
```

It works now, but I don't want to use the `for` value of `contact_first_name` to grab that form element.  I want to use the displayed label text as I am able to with The `Title` and `Last Name`.

[image]

What am I missing?  Why can't I use "First Name" to grab the First Name form element?

**Update**:  It turns out that if I put `sleep 1` right before `fill_in "First Name", with: "foo" then it works!  According to comments below from @TomWalpole, it seems like there is a javascript library that is getting in the way?  Below are all the javascripts I include in:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery.turbolinks
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require turbolinks
//= require bootstrap-sprockets
//= require twitter/typeahead.min
//= require nested_form_fields
```

Comment: What driver are you using? And what error exactly do you get?

Comment: @TomWalpole I've been trying both selenium and webkit.  The error is just my validation error that the First Name can't be blank.  It is doing this because after capybara submits the page: the submission was invalid since capybara did not submit a first name.

Comment: Ok -- so what that tells me is that Capybara is actually finding the element and filling it in, otherwise it would raise an ElementNotFound error.  The most likely cause is some kind of JS library (validation?) that's augmenting the input and running after capybara has actually filled the field and ends up clearing what capybara put in it, you can test that by putting a `sleep 10` before the first fill_in  -- if that is the case then we need to figure out what change whatever library it is makes to the page thats detectable, and wait for that before filling in

Comment: @TomWalpole wow, ok so as you suggested I put `sleep 5` right before doing `fill_in "First Name", with: "foo", and it worked!  could you explain once more why putting `sleep 5` before filling in the first form element made capybara properly fill in the first form element?

Comment: Because you have some JS library that is adding functionality/behavior to the input.  Capybara is finding the element and filling it in before whatever JS is running has added its functionality to the input. Once the JS has augmented the input it is resetting its value to the inputs value property (as opposed to the value attribute which has been changed) which ends up setting it back to blank.  What libraries are you using on the page?

Comment: @TomWalpole I update day question with my js library at the bottom of the question.  Thanks for helping!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106939/discussion-between-tom-walpole-and-neil).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Capybara is actually finding the input and filling it in, but then the value is being removed.  This is because you have some JS library that is adding functionality/behavior to the input after the Capybara has filled in the element. Once the JS has augmented the input it is resetting its value to the inputs value property (as opposed to the value attribute which has been changed) which ends up setting it back to blank. Sleeping before the first fill_in is a workaround, other than that it would mean figuring out what JS is being run on the element and waiting for a detectable change (if there are any) before calling fill_in.

Comment: I have the exact same issue with Rails 5 and Turbolinks 5, testing with capybara-webkit 1.11. When I enable Turbolinks, a fill_in for an E-Mail field on a password reset page doesn't work reliable anymore, which is very unfortunate

Comment: @cseelus You need to look at what JS widgets you're attaching to that field and see if they add a class, data attribute, or any other detectable change to the field and then wait for that to exist before calling fill_in

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply. I viewed the separate stackoverflow chat discussion between you and the author of this question and read everything I could find about this issue. I'm at this issue for more than two hours now, as putting `sleep` before `fill_in` just isn't clean imho.
I'm quite sure it is Turbolinks, as I threw out all other JS stuff except for jQuery and jQuery UJS and only when I throw out Turbolinks itself, the `fill_in` works reliable as expected.

Comment: I have not attached any widget whatsoever to this text field (app is still quite basic and clean atm) so I guess I just have to grab the element by ID for now, which also is flaky, but I guess I don't have any other options when I want to keep Turbolinks (and capybara-webkit for integration testing).

Comment: @cseelus Maybe you should open a new question and show exactly what you're doing.  If you're not adding widgets then your issue is not the same as this issue was.

Comment: My problem was that I used a `fill_in 'E-Mail'` on a password reset form, starting from a login form. I went there with `click_link 'Forgot password?'`. After extensive tests, I realized the problem was that Capybara in maybe 1/20 cases filled in the email field on the login page, instead of the reset password page and did that only when Turbolinks was enabled. A simple `within('form#reset_password') { fill_in 'E-Mail' … }` did the trick (`sleep` between `click_link` and `fill_in` also works, but I try to avoid that). Thanks for your time and for Capybara, which is great!

Answer (score 0):

If slow page loading is the case and especially if some Javascript and / or CSS animation is involved, then try raising the `Capybara.default_max_wait_time` to e.g. 30 seconds (the default is 2 seconds). And the `fill_in` should start working.

The `fill_in`, as well as most other Capybara methods, is "synchronized", i.e. it retries searching for the field up to the default max wait time and only if it is not found after this time, it fails.

See the [Capybara readme](https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara#asynchronous-javascript-ajax-and-friends).

Comment: Unfortunately the issue does not seem to be the wait time.  It seams that Capybara is just  unable to find the first element on forms via the text displayed within the label.  The only way around it I found is to display the `for` attribute value of the label instead.  So for first name it would be changed from: `fill_in "First Name", with: "foo"`, To:  `fill_in "contact_first_name", with: "foo"`

Comment: I see. It seems better to use the ids to me anyway. But let me throw one last wild little guess: would the field be found if you searched for "* First Name" ? I understand that the asterisk is defined in CSS rather than HTML but still... You can print texts of all labels using this: `puts page.all('label').map(&:text).inspect` in your test. Perhaps you'll find out that Capybara sees the labels differently.

Comment: Thanks for the tip.  It came back with this `"[\"First Name\", \"Last Name\"]"`.  I don't think that helps me here, but it is good to know that it exists.